# How to deploy App Service with Azure Container Registry by cdktf

Tags: typescript, docker, azure-appservice, azure-container-registry, cdktf

I am trying to create an App Service with Azure Container Registry with CDKTF and Provider AzureRM 2.70.0 (also tried with the latest)
While I wrote these codes

```
this.appService = new AppService(this, "iShare App", {
            name: process.env.PROJECT_NAME! + process.env.ENV,
            resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
            location: resourceGroup.location,
            appServicePlanId: appServicePlan.id,
            dependsOn: [appServicePlan],
            appSettings: {
                "WEBSITES_PORT" : "5000",
                "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL" : props.containerregistry.containerRegistry.loginServer,
                "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" : props.containerregistry.containerRegistry.adminUsername,
                "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" : props.containerregistry.containerRegistry.adminPassword,
            },
            kind: "linux",
            siteConfig: {
                linuxfxversion: "DOCKER|isharedemotest3dev.azurecr.io/isharedemotest3-hades:2fb17de",
                always_on: true,
                health_check_path: "/health",
            }
}
```

and this error pop out

```
TS2322: Type '{ linuxfxversion: string; always_on: true; health_check_path: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AppServiceSiteConfig[]'.   
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'linuxfxversion' does not exist in type 'AppServiceSiteConfig[]'. 
app-service.d.ts(118, 14): The expected type comes from property 'siteConfig' which is declared here on type 'AppServiceConfig'
```

on app-service.d.ts

```
readonly siteConfig?: AppServiceSiteConfig[];
    /**
     * source_control block.
     *
     * Docs at Terraform Registry: {@link https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service#source_control AppService#source_control}
     *
     * @stability stable
     */
```

which there is an option of linuxfxversion but it is still an error ( have tried any letter case, same result)

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `[]` missing on the siteConfig attribute.

It should be

```
siteConfig: [{
                linuxfxversion: "DOCKER|isharedemotest3dev.azurecr.io/isharedemotest3-hades:2fb17de",
                always_on: true,
                health_check_path: "/health",
            }]
```

The background here is that siteConfig can have multiple entries (at least according to the Terraform provider schema), therefore you need to wrap it in an array.